# Creating a Graticule with Nested Loops

Tags: loops, nested, leaflet, polyline

How do you loop polylines to make a graticule in leaflet?

I need nested loops to create a graticule.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use [Leaflet.Graticule](https://github.com/turban/Leaflet.Graticule) or if you want to roll your own take a look at the [source](https://github.com/turban/Leaflet.Graticule/blob/master/L.Graticule.js) to see how he/she did it